# Mongodb join query from nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to **MongoDB** and trying to join two query and store result in a single model. I want to fetch client name from another collection while fetching client task.

**Model:-**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

const ClientTaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  clientId: {
    type: Number
  },  
  taskId: {
    type: Number
  },
  clientTaskId: {
    type: Number
  },
  active: {
    type: Boolean
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('ClientTask', ClientTaskSchema);
```

**Controller:-**

```
module.exports.getClientByTask = function(req, res) {
var query = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
ClientTask.find({taskId: query.taskId}, function(err, clientTask) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!clientTask) {
        res.status(200).json({ success: false, message: 'Somthing went wrong. Please contact admin.'});
    }
    else {
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Successfull', data: clientTask});
    }
});
};
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to pass `clientId` as a reference:

```
clientId: {
 type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client / or whatever your model'
}
```

Then you'll be able to use Mongoose's `populate` method http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

```
ClientTask
  .find({ taskId: query.taskId })
  .populate('clientId', { name: 1 }).exec(function (err, clientTask) {
    if (!clientTask) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: 'Client task not found' })
    }
   // your logic
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch aggregated data with mongodb aggregate. To Calculates aggregate values for the data in a collection:

$lookup Performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database to filter in documents from the “joined” collection for processing. To each input document, the $lookup stage adds a new array field whose elements are the matching documents from the “joined” collection. The $lookup stage passes these reshaped documents to the next stage.

In your case:

```
Model.ClientTask.aggregate([
  {
     $lookup:
      {
          from: "client",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "clientId",
          as: "clientData"
      },
  }, 
  {
    $project: {
              "name": clientData.name,   // This name will be client name from client collections
              "taskId": 1,
              "clientTaskId": 1,
              "active": 1
     }
  }
],
function (err, response) {
   console.log(err, response)
});
```