# Populate() Mongoose is not returning joined data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Well, I´am trying to retrieve Name and Lastname from user who created the document but it´s not working, it still returning Mongo´s Id

This is my **areas model**

```
var mongo     = require('mongoose'),
    validator = require('mongoose-unique-validator'),
    Schema    = mongo.Schema


var model = new Schema({
    NAME:       { type: String, required: true, unique: true, max: 50, min: 3 },
    STATUS:     { type: String, default: 'active' },
    ADDED_BY:   { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
    ADDED_DATE: { type: Date, default: Date.now }


}, {collection :'areas'})

model.plugin( validator, { message: 'The {PATH} is not valid or duplicated' } )
module.exports = mongo.model('Area', model )
```

This is the **user model**

```
var mongo     = require('mongoose'),
    validator = require('mongoose-unique-validator'),
    Schema = mongo.Schema

var userSchema = new Schema({
    PERSONAL_DATA: {
        NAME:            { type: String, required: [ true, 'The name is necessary' ], max: 50 },
        LAST_NAME:       { type: String, required: [ true, 'the lastname is necessary' ], max: 100 },
        PHOTO:           { type: String, max: 100 },
        BIRTHDAY:        { type: Date },
        MARITIAL_STATUS: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'maritial_statuses' },
        GENDER:          { type: String, max: 1 },
        EMAIL:           { type: String, required: true  },
    },
    COMPANY_DATA: {
        JOB:      { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'jobs' },
        AREA:     { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'areas' },
        ROLE:     { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'roles' },
        BOSS:     { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
    }
}, { collection: 'users' } )

model.plugin( validator, { message: 'The {PATH} is not valid or duplicated' } )

module.exports = mongo.model('User', userSchema )
```

And this is my **areas route**

```
var express = require('express'),
    model   = require('../../models/catalogs/areas'),
    app     = express()


app.get('/:from', (req, res) => {

    var from = parseInt( req.params.from )

    model.find()
        .sort('NAME').populate({ path: 'users', select: 'NAME LAST_NAME'})
        .limit(10).skip(from)
        .exec((error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    success: false,
                    error
                })
            }

            res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                data
            })
        })
})

module.exports = app
```

The response is

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "STATUS": "active",
            "_id": "5c547f4adadf433914f72c8c",
            "NAME": "Contabilidad y Finanzas",
            "ADDED_BY": "5c4f562deec6f4defeea759b",
            "ADDED_DATE": "2019-02-01T17:18:02.680Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "STATUS": "active",
            "_id": "5c547f3edadf433914f72c8b",
            "NAME": "Tecnologías",
            "ADDED_BY": "5c4f562deec6f4defeea759b",
            "ADDED_DATE": "2019-02-01T17:17:50.579Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

As you seen, ADDED_BY is a field joined to Users and I want to retrieve that information. I don´t know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Your Model doesn’t have LAST_NAME, only NAME so it won’t be returned..

Comment: well, LAST_NAME is not in Areas model but is in Users model

Comment: You may have to create a joined Model from both of these Models, then it will populate..

Comment: I added the User model

Comment: For populate() example is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51558219/10634638

Comment: I did like that men

Comment: You not using “ref:” inside your schema which joins one table to the other.. last link I gave had more info about ref: inside Mongo dB documentation

Comment: `NAME LAST_NAME` are inside `PERSONAL_DATA` not in `root` document

Comment: I tried to use PERSONAL_DATA.LAST_NAME as the populate I can´t do it :(